# How to use JSF datatable in Struts2?

Tags: java, jsf, datatable, struts

I have worked with JSF, so pretty much delighted with [JSF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaServer_Faces) [datatable](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/javaserverfaces/1.2/docs/tlddocs/h/dataTable.html). Is there any similar kind of thing in Struts 2(V2.3.1.2)? or any alternative? Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're basically interested in rendering tables from databases/collections, then you might want to take a look at [DisplayTag](http://www.displaytag.org/1.2/). It's mature and popular and works pretty well for JSP.